# CCleaner Disable and Enable Startup Programs

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, ccleaner

I am working on a program for work which includes a startup manager.  I have it to where the user can delete startup entries for programs, but it cannot disable startup entries.

With the CCleaner program a user has the ability to enable or disable.   Can anyone give insight on how they are able to accomplish that?  I have looked around in the registry but I don't see any differences to the keys when the startup is enable or disabled.  Is this set in another location?

Edit:
I used RegFromApp to monitor the registry while enabling and disabling startup on numerous programs.  Turns out it actually creates keys if they don't already exist.

Comment: why reinvent the wheel?  msconfig.exe (built) into windows can enable/disable startup programs.  Why create a new one?

Comment: As a sys admin I don't give the users rights to msconfig.  I have developed a program to where they can do these kinds of task, but without breaking their machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am not the developer of CCleaner I can't give you exact details on how they might manage this, but in general entries under:

32bit:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MsConfig`

64bit :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MsConfig
```

will house "disabled" startup entries.

Comment: Might want to correct your paths. There's no `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Software` or `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Software` as far as I can see.

Comment: The 64 bit path is correct. For 32 bit just remove the 2nd Software

Comment: Ahh good catch, that was an error on my part, its been corrected

Comment: @Kevin_: Must confess I'm *still* not seeing `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Software` in regedit (and I've checked on 2 PCs now with Win7 x64).

Comment: @Karan Interesting.  Are you trying to do the same thing that I am?

Comment: @Kevin_: Not really, but your query did get me thinking about something so was just checking it out. :)

Comment: @Karan I see.  Well what I wound up doing was monitoring the registry to see what all was going on.  You can do it with any executable by monitoring the process with RegFromApp.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in two possibilities:

- Disabled startup entries are stored in a configuration file (. ini).
- In the registry editor these values ​​are stored in:
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\MsConfig\startupreg`.

Comment: Wonder how come two people posted `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Software` as a valid path? Is this path actually present on your PC, because I don't see it at all in regedit.

Comment: I didn't see it either.  I tested on a 32 bit machine and a 64 bit.